# Who kept a blog for a year with a new game idea every day, and where is it?

Tags: game-design, assets, blog

There's this indie game developer who tried to come up with a new original idea for a game every day for a year - and he put all his thoughts on his website. **+200 ideas** so far, if I remember correctly.

I don't remember the URL to his site, or the name of the author. Anyone know what I'm talking about?

[Delete this post if it doesn't belong here! Just wanted to add it to the blog thread if I managed to find it]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a list of one item. Although it is about game development, it is not about resolving an issue related to developing a game.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you mean [Squidi's 300 Game Mechanics.](http://www.squidi.net/three/index.php).

I wonder how many of those have gotten actual use.  I know the light/dark idea (his first 3 posts) got implemented as fairly popular flash games, but I don't know if he did that or someone else did.

Comment: Thanks! Will mark this as an answer. Added the link to the blog thread!

Answer (score 11):

Patrick Curry did "A new game idea every week" a few years ago:

http://www.patrickcurry.com/thoughts/